# How to use variable values in salt formula?

Tags: salt-stack

Consider my SLS file,

```
state1:
 cmd.run:
  - order: 1
  - name: |
     USER_NAME='username'
     USERPWD='password'
     DB_NAME='test'
     USER_TOBE_CREATED='new_user'
     PASSWORD='newpass'

 mysql_user.present:
  - order: 2
  - host: localhost
  - username: USER_TOBE_CREATED
  - password: PASSWORD
  - connection_user: USER_NAME
  - connection_pass: USERPWD
  - connection_charset: utf8
  - saltenv:
     - LC_ALL: "en_US.utf8"

 mysql_grants.present:
  - order: 3
  - grant: all privileges
  - database: DB_NAME.*
  - user: USER_TOBE_CREATED
```

In the states mysql_user.present and mysql_grants.present I am using the variables USER_TOBE_CREATED,USER_NAME,USERPWD etc whose values are assigned in state cmd.run. How will I make these two following states to use the actual values of those variables?. Here it's taking variable name itself as the value.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to declare the variables in the state file itself, i.e.:

`{% set user_name = "name" %}`

and:

```
state1:
 cmd.run:
  - order: 1
  - name: |
     USER_NAME='{{ user_name }}'
```

You can re-use the variable as many times as you want inside the state file.
Let me know if this helped.